# Scanning and Recognizing Highlighted Text

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, highlighting

This question was asked on an Adobe Acrobat forum. I am posting here since I am looking to solve the same task, but don't require that the solution use Adobe Acrobat.

> Is there a way to print a PDF: Highlight with a marker by hand. Then rescan the document and the software shall recognize the highlighted text and then highlight it "electronically" in the PDF.
>   The reason is that I need to print it out as I need multiple pages to lay next to each other and highlight the text with a marker. It is just more practicle for reading scientific publications.

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1384310

Comment: Most OCR tries to ignore artifacts that are not part of the characters.  Highlight reduces the contrast and degrades recognition.  I would be surprised if any OCR package did what you want.  But if one did, it would be very dependent on the color you use.  Some colors are detected much better than others and different colors convert to grayscale or black and white at different darknesses/densities.  It would be a balance between being detected and degrading the text, so you would want to experiment with different highlighter colors.